# Is there a way to update UISnapBehavior anchor point?

Tags: uikit

I'm building a custom container view that is a stack of cards piling on top of each other (each card is a child view controller.)

Now there is a motion where the user could "pick up" the card and I am currently implementing it like this:

1. On first touch-down-inside, I adds a UISnapBehavior. The card "snaps" during a small duration onto the user's finger.
2. After a small delay, UISnapBehavior is removed and UIAttachmentBehavior is put in place (so I can update the anchor point as the user moves his finger around.)

Now this presents 2 problems:

1. If the user moves his/her finger while UISnapBehavior is active, I'll remove the snap behavior and replace it with UIAttachmentBehavior but doing this causes a visible visual glitch where the card bounce a bit before attaching to the finger. This is in a small duration but still very visible.
2. If I use UIAttachmentBehavior directly, I cannot configure it to work in the same way the snap behavior works. Either there is too much spring animation or too little snapping feels.

Now what I wanted is the following:

- When the user first touch the card, the card should snap onto the finger (there is a designated anchor point on the card where the finger should goes, so that point snaps to the finger when the card is touched)
- When the user moves the card, the card should moves along with the finger.
- When the user release the finger (touch-up) there should be a small residual acceleration going, this is already done using a UIDynamicItemBehavior.

So is there a way I can get UISnapBehavior-style attachment (to the finger) but still allows the anchor to move around?

Do I need to roll my own custom behavior for this?